# Given a network N, show that the resultant flow out of the sources is equal to the resultant flow into the sources.

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

***Problem:***
Let $f$ be a flow in a network $N = (V,X,Y,c)$ with vertice-set $V$, source-set $X$ and sink-set $Y$, and capacity function $c$ . Show that the resultant flow out of the sources is equal to the resultant flow into the sources.

***Thoughts:*** I know the resultant flow out of a sub-set of a network is equal to $f^{out}(X) - f^{in}(X)$ , (the negative of which is the resultant flow into a subset)
and so the problem amounts to showing that

$f^{out}(X) - f^{in}(X) = f^{in}(Y) - f^{out}(X)$.

I am stuck and need a hint to progress as I am not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that we have
$$
\sum_{v \in V} f^{out}(v) = \sum_{v \in V} f^{in}(v) \tag{$1$}
$$
since the flow on each edge contributes the same amount to both the LHS and the RHS of $(1)$. In addition, by definition of a flow, we have
$$
f^{out}(v) = f^{in}(v) \quad\text{for } \forall v \not \in X \cup Y \tag{$2$}
$$
By $(1)$ and $(2)$, we then have
$$
\sum_{v \in X \cup Y} f^{out}(v) = \sum_{v \in X \cup Y} f^{in}(v)
$$
Since $X \cap Y = \emptyset$, the conclusion is immediate then.

Comment: I don't see how the conclusion is immediate, can you elaborate on the final step?

Comment: @TheMathNoob We have $$\sum_{v \in X}f^{out}(v) + \sum_{v \in Y}f^{out}(v) = \sum_{v \in X}f^{in}(v) + \sum_{v \in Y}f^{in}(v)$$ which implies $$\sum_{v \in X}f^{out}(v) - \sum_{v \in X}f^{in}(v)  = \sum_{v \in Y}f^{in}(v) - \sum_{v \in Y}f^{out}(v)$$Note that $$\sum_{v \in X}f^{out}(v) - \sum_{v \in X}f^{in}(v)  = f^{out}(X) - f^{in}(X)$$  Similarly for $Y$.